# Multiple configuration vs Multiple entries in webpack

Tags: javascript, node.js, webpack

So, I have a multi-page react application. I am bundling the pages using webpack. I have two choices, either I use multiple configuration i.e export [conf1,conf2] or add multiple entries i.e entry: {index : "index.js",about:"about.js"}.

Now, which one is the better one in the terms of speed and code splitting.
I sort of guess that webpack spawns multiple compiler instances when using multiple configs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Webpack doesn't run multi compiler configuration parallelly. If one wants to run them parallelly then they might use [Parralel Webpack](https://www.npmjs.com/package/parallel-webpack)